# LogCat goes crazy (Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I'm noticing a strange behaviour when i plug in any android device to my computer.
It starts showing some messages in the LogCat in Eclipse as soon as i plug it in. Same thing with my HTC and ASUS tablet.

This has never happened before and I dont remember doing anything out of ordinary when I developed my app yesterday.

Any1 has an idea how to stop this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to set a filter in Logcat window (+-Button) to only show outputs from your app

Comment: It's normal.  When a device (pre-Honeycomb) connects, the complete current logcat is read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience it's perfectly normal for the logcat to start displaying messages as soon as you plug in a device. At the least it means it's working! ;)

However, once you start building and running your application and picking up errors the specific filter for your application will start displaying which will only show logs pertaining to your app.

It's set by default to switch to your app once an error displays, but you can change that default by going to Preferences > Android > LogCat and changing "Show logcat view..." from "Error" to "Verbose" or whatever works. That way it will switch to showing your application's logs faster. Beyond that, you can do further specific filters.

Hope that helps XD

Comment: Oh, and now that I see what they've posted above, I agree; sometimes it simply doesn't show up right away or the window isn't up and you don't realize it. All I know is that I learned something just now, cause I always hated forcing an error to happen to get my application specific logcat to show up XD

Answer (score 2):

You can add filters to the logcat so that you only show relevant information.

Comment: I've just noticed all this filters in the dropdown menu (verbose, assets, warns...) maybe I've shanged some of those. Which one is chosen for you as a default one ?

Answer (score 0):

This can't be stopped as such as the log cat in eclipse will retrieve anything where logging is being done of some sort whether it is an app, or android itself.

You can filter it, I think at the top of the log cat window there is a text field to only show log messages that contain a certain string and If I remember correctly there are also buttons to the right to only show error messages or warning or both etc.

Comment: Ok guys.Thanks for your answer.
But as I've said, this has never happened until this morning.

how can that be?

Comment: Maybe you didn't have the logcat window open or you had some default filter that filtered out everything that has been removed now?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Nexus 5. Eclipse wouldn't recognize the device, so I messed around with the device window a bit and then the log cat started to go crazy.

After several reboots, I un-checked the USB debugging option in the phone's Developer settings and re-checked it.

Problem solved.

I think something in the Device window changed when I performed this action, but I'm not certain.